# Opening, spliting and sorting into an Arrray in perl

Tags: perl

I am a beginner programmer, who has been given a weeklong assignment to build a complex program, but is having a difficult time starting off. I have been given a set of data, and the goal is separate it into two separate arrays by the second column, based on whether the letter is M or F. 
this is the code I have thus far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

open (FILE, "ssbn1898.txt");
$x=<FILE>;
split/[,]/$x;
@array1=$y;
if @array1[2]="M";
print @array2;
else;
print @array3;
close (FILE);
```

How do I fixed this? Please try and use the simplest terms possible I stared coding last week!
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show the contents of your data file, and your expected output.

Comment: Hello, welcome. Code is a good start. Example input and output helps too though. I'll point out your first problem is likely that you're looking at index `2` of the array. Perl arrays start at zero, so the second column is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

First off - you split on comma, so I'm going to assume your data looks something like this:

```
one,M
two,F
three,M
four,M
five,F
six,M
```

There's a few problems with your code:

- turn on `strict` and `warnings`. The warn you about possible problems with your code
- open is better off written as `open ( my $input, "<", $filename ) or die $!;`
- You only actually read one line from `<FILE>` - because if you assign it to a scalar `$x` it only reads one line.
- you don't actually insert your value into either array.

So to do what you're basically trying to do:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#define your arrays. 
my @M_array;
my @F_array; 

#open your file. 
open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt') or die $!;

#read file one at a time - this sets the implicit variable $_ each loop, 
#which is what we use for the split. 
while ( <$input> ) {
    #remove linefeeds
    chomp;
    #capture values from either side of the comma. 
    my ( $name, $id ) = split ( /,/ ); 

    #test if id is M. We _assume_ that if it's not, it must be F. 
    if ( $id eq "M" ) {
        #insert it into our list. 
        push ( @M_array, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( @F_array, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );

#print the results
print "M: @M_array\n";
print "F: @F_array\n";
```

You could probably do this more concisely - I'd suggest perhaps looking at hashes next, because then you can associate key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `part` function in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) that does exactly what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::MoreUtils 'part';

my ($f, $m) = part { (split /,/)[1] eq 'M' } <DATA>;

say "M: @$m";
say "F: @$f";

__END__
one,M,foo
two,F,bar
three,M,baz
four,M,foo
five,F,bar
six,M,baz
```

The output is:

```
M: one,M,foo
 three,M,baz
 four,M,foo
 six,M,baz

F: two,F,bar
 five,F,bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; 
my @boys=();
my @girls=();
my $fname="ssbn1898.txt";  # I keep stuff like this in a scalar
open (FIN,"< $fname")
       or die "$fname:$!";
while ( my $line=<FIN> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @f=split(",",$line);
    push @boys,$f[0] if $f[1]=~ m/[mM]/;
    push @girls,$f[1] if $f[1]=~ m/[gG]/;
}
print Dumper(\@boys);
print Dumper(\@girls);
exit 0;
#  Caveats:
#       Code is not tested but should work and definitely shows the concepts
#
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the same thing...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my (@m,@f);

while(<>){
  push (@m,$1) if(/(.*),M/);
  push (@f,$1) if(/(.*),F/);
}

print "M=@m\nF=@f\n";
```

Or a "perl -n" (=for all lines do) variant:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

push (@m,$1) if(/(.*),M/);
push (@f,$1) if(/(.*),F/);

END { print "M=@m\nF=@f\n";}
```